# Connecting neo4j shell to embedded neo4j in java

Tags: neo4j

[neo4j: 2.1.3, Windows 7 64 bit, Java 7]

I want to be able to connect to the embedded neo4j database in java, using the neo4j shell.
As suggested [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-remote-shell-combined) adding the property remote_shell_enabled="true" should do that.

I tried as suggested but my shell is not able to connect to the db with error

> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock
>   on store lock file:
>   ~\store_lock. Please ensure no
>   other process is using this database, and that the directory is
>   writable (required even for read-only access)
>
> at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:82)

I set the property as follows in my code

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DBPATH).setConfig("remote_shell_enabled","true").newGraphDatabase();
```

Also, doing this results in the database not shutting down through the shutdown hook. Instead the process does not end, seemingly the shutdown hook is never executed.

If however I use the below to start the property the shutdown hook is executed successfully everytime.

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DBPATH);
```

or

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DBPATH).newGraphDatabase();
```

Is there some other way to enable the shell access to the embedded database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to open the neo4j-shell server at e.g. port 5000, start the database with something like

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DB_DIR)
            .setConfig(ShellSettings.remote_shell_enabled, "true")
            .setConfig(ShellSettings.remote_shell_port, "5000")
            .newGraphDatabase();
```

and the connect to it using

```
neo4j-shell -port 5000
```

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes that worked.
I was starting the shell with the -path option instead of the host port .